# When using the “Remote Server Administration Tools” on Windows 7 (or Vista), is there a way to make the tools (such as DHCP or DNS) remember servers that I work with on a regular basis?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7

When using the “Remote Server Administration Tools” on Windows 7 (or Vista), is there a way to make the tools (such as DHCP or DNS) remember servers that I work with on a regular basis?

Comment: Are you saying that you have to reconfigure each of these tools every time you use them?  I don't think that is the default behavior, but I cannot replicate until tomorrow.

Comment: Every time I open the DHCP manager for example, I have to add my server to it, instead of it just remembering the server from the last time I used it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the default behavior of those tools to "forget".

The only way I know of around this is to create a MMC, which is handy because you centralize several tools in one window.

Here is the method I use for having those tools remember your servers:

- Start > Run > mmc.exe
- File > Add/Remove Snap In
- Select DNS, DHCP, Hit "add", click Ok
- Right click DNS, Add Servers
- Right click DHCP, Add Servers

Lastly, you save your new custom Management Console:

- File > Save As > servers.msc

Next time you open servers.msc all of your servers will be there.

Cheers

Comment: Ok, one issue. Every time I open my new MMC console, UAC comes up and asks me if I'm sure. Anyway around that?

Comment: Hi Corey, unfortunately UAC doesnt have a whitelist option. I've grown accustomed to "alt+c" to dismiss the prompts. I just came across this funky/hacky solution:

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-programs-elevated-without-getting-the-uac-prompt/

Comment: Looks like you can disable UAC prompting without disabling UAC altogether: http://4sysops.com/archives/why-and-how-to-disable-the-uac-elevation-prompts-secure-desktop-prompting/